# Вывод сообщения в System tray QT

Tags: c++, qt, строки, qstring

Всем добрый день!

Столкнулся с проблемой при выводе сообщения в System Tray. Клиент получает дейтаграмму с сервера, дальше переводит её в QString и после этого должен отправить системное уведомление. Дело в том, что уведомление отправляется, но оно пустое, есть только тема. Понимаю, что где-то перемудрил с типами данных, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

```
myDatagram.resize(my_udp->pendingDatagramSize());
my_udp->readDatagram(myDatagram.data(),myDatagram.size());
QString myString = QString::fromStdString(myDatagram.toStdString());
const char* str = myString.toStdString().c_str();
mySystemTrayIcon->showMessage(tr("Server"), tr(str));
```

С дейтаграммой, переведенной в QString, проблем нет, она приходит (проверял выводом через QMessageBox). тут, скорее, я неправильно использую showMessage для mySystemTrayIcon.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А если по-простому: `mySystemTrayIcon->showMessage(tr("Server"), myString);`?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin То же самое. При этом если я вручную пропишу там какой-то  текст, например: `mySystemTrayIcon->showMessage(tr("Server"), tr("Hello");` то всё работает

Comment: зачем вы используете tr() не понимая, что это такое?

Answer (score 3):

В выражении `const char* str = myString.toStdString().c_str();` создается временный объект `std::string`, который сразу же уничтожается, оставляя вас с невалидным указателем.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю точно в какой кодировке приходят данные по UDP, предположим что в UTF-8.

```
myDatagram.resize(my_udp->pendingDatagramSize());
my_udp->readDatagram(myDatagram.data(),myDatagram.size());
QString myString = QString::fromUtf8(myDatagram);
mySystemTrayIcon->showMessage(tr("Server"), tr(myString.toUtf8()));
```

Вот так делать вообще нельзя скорее всего, так как пытаетесь использовать `str` после того как объякт `std::string` уже уничтожен.

```
const char* str = myString.toStdString().c_str();
```